# What is the correct name for bytes which are to be signed?

Tags: signature, dsa, terminology

I have some bytes, and I sign them with my private key using ECDSA. The resultant (71) bytes are the signature.

But what is the name of the bytes I have signed? (If this were encryption, they would be called "plaintext".)

Comment: Although message can also be used to mean input for other functions or it could be used as a more generic term. So calling it the "message to be signed" or "signed message" would be a good idea in case the context is not sufficiently clear.

Comment: When the point is to distinguish the "pre-signature" value (like pre-crime in _Minority Report_?) it is sometimes labelled "TBS" for "To Be Signed" e.g. X.509/PKIX http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.1 .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct term for bytes to be signed is *“message”*.

Generally, it does not really matter if a message to be signed is human readable or not. Sometimes, you may also find it mentioned as *“digital message”*… which practically is the same and merely extends the term to explicitly hint at the fact the message is digitally stored and/or processed.

References showing the use of the term can be found at various sources. For example: scientific papers and websites talking about cryptography and/or cryptanalysis in relation to digital signatures.

For your convenience, here are a couple of quotes showing its usage (bold-italic emphasis is mine):

### randomly picked, yet well-known websites

- source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature

  > … Digitally signed ***messages*** may be anything representable as a bitstring: examples include electronic mail, contracts, or a message sent via some other cryptographic protocol. …
- source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Secure-messages-with-a-digital-signature-549ca2f1-a68f-4366-85fa-b3f4b5856fc6

  > … By digitally signing a ***message***, you apply your unique digital mark to the ***message***. … This information proves to the recipient that you signed the contents of the ***message*** …

### randomly picked, yet well-known crypto-related papers

- source: [Identity-based cryptosystems and signature schemes](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-39568-7_5) by A Shamir - Advances in cryptology, 1985

  > … However, when g is known, there is a very simple way to generate any number of signatures of any ***message*** even when the factorization of n is unknown. To sign the ***message*** m, the user chooses a random number r …
- source: [A digital signature based on a conventional encryption function](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48184-2_32) by RC Merkle – Advances in Cryptology (CRYPTO'87), 1988

  > … If A wishes to sign ***message*** m …
- source: [Group signatures](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-46416-6_22.pdf) by D Chaum, E Van Heyst – Advances in Cryptology (Eurocrypt'91), 1991

  > … If person i wants to sign ***message*** n, he chooses randomly some set r of persons (including himself); his signature will be … If person i wants to sign ***message*** m=An), he randomly chooses …
- source: [The exact security of digital signatures-How to sign with RSA and Rabin](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-68339-9_34) by M Bellare, P Rogaway – Advances in Cryptology (Eurocrypt'96), 1996

  > … In order to sign ***message*** M , the signer first picks a random
  > seed T of length …